# Mongoose: Group by per month with the timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I group by per month and do the average of qty, in mongoose, having only the field timestamp?

`{
"timestamp": 1234567890,
"qty": 3
},
{
"timestamp": 09876543322,
"qty": 5
}`

I want to know the average on qty for each month.

Answer (score 6):

If your 'timestamp' field is a Date-typed value, then you can use the
`$month` projection operator from the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operators/#date-operators) to grab
the month from your timestamp, then `group` by that:

```
collection.aggregate([
    // Grab the month of the timestamp
    {$project: {"qty":1, "month":{$month: "$timestamp"}}},
    // Find average for each month
    {$group: {"_id":"$month", "avg_qty":{$avg:"$qty"}}}
])
```

If timestamp is just a number, you could use  [map-reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/). Something
similar to this:

```
var o = {};
// Get the month and qty for each document, grouping into months
o.map = function() { emit( (new Date(this.timestamp)).getMonth(), this.qty); };
// Get the average qty for each month
o.reduce = function(month, quants) { return Array.sum(quants)/quants.length; };

collection.mapReduce(o, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```